# Access 10' with SQL Server DB 'Operation must use an updateable query'

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 'front-end' DB that has its data stored in a SQL Server DB 'back-end.'I'm trying to write the most simple UPDATE query I can and being met with this error: 'Operation must use an updateable query.' My qry code is:

```
UPDATE tblTableLastModifiedDates SET LastModified = NOW()
WHERE id='1';
```

A lot of this DB was set up before I got this job so the dumb table names are not my fault. Also, I checked the tblTableLastModifiedDates and it actually has no PK and I've been unable to create one. I'm not sure if that is the problem.

Before I scrap all this and start it over (to do it the right way), I figured I'd ask if anyone knew how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error implies that `tblTableLastModifiedDates` is a view that is not unique enough to update the `LastModified` field in the underlying table. This isn't that uncommon.

The best approach is going to be to execute the `UPDATE` against the underlying table.

Comment: So, the data that the LastModified stamp is in reference too? Should I  avoid using the tblTableLastModifiedDates? 

I'm sorry, I don't understand what this means: "a view that is not unique enough to update the LastModified field in the underlying table."

Comment: @Couchcommando, `tblTableLastModifiedDates` is a `View` logically. That means it's a `SELECT` statement that produces a result set and is a collection of tables. There are times that a `View` is in fact updatable, but there are times that the result set has duplicates and or a primary key field for the record you're trying to update is missing from the result set. That makes the `View` read only. I would recommend just updating the underlying table instead (the table `LastModified` is *actually* coming from).

Comment: I used your suggestion and stored the information in the underlying table. Thanks!